# Wi-Fi just won't work on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

I was able to use Wi-Fi on my Ubuntu 17.10 before I changed the name and password of my router. Since then I have been unable to use the internet. My network manger is  not even showing available devices. I tried all the steps from the link on Askubuntu : [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal)

Here is what I get when I try to use the `wpa_supplicant` method:

```
skywalker@lancelot ~ % sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlp2s0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff (SSID='lancelot' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff (SSID='lancelot' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp2s0: Associated with 7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff (SSID='lancelot' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff (SSID='lancelot' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp2s0: Associated with 7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=7a:ff:ca:3a:30:ff reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
```

Here are further details

```
skywalker@lancelot ~ % lspci -knn |grep Net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
[8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1028:0493]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1121]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
skywalker@lancelot ~ % uname -a                        
Linux lancelot 4.13.0-21-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 18 17:29:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
skywalker@lancelot ~ % rfkill list       
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
skywalker@lancelot ~ %
```

My question is,  **How do I set up my Wi-Fi to be able to connect to any router and use the internet?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71015/discussion-on-question-by-skywalker-wi-fi-just-wont-work-on-ubuntu-17-10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `dmesg` (comments) :

```
[   34.083148] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   77.913658] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

mean that the configuration of the IPv6 is failed , to solve the problem disable the IPv6 following the steps described on the debian wiki :[How_to_turn_off_IPv6](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6)